# How to update maven package after commit/pull-request

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I am using a package https://github.com/dhatim/fastexcel, resently there was a commit in their repo, but the version had not been changed in Readme(description) of package in git hub, how can I update the package using maven?

I tried to run mvn release:update-versions, but I get this error

[image]

Then I run mvn release:update-versions -X

[image]

[image]

This is my pom.xml

[image]

Comment: What version did not change in what description? Why the java tag?

Comment: in the git package documentation

Comment: Update you question with the complete maven Error and the pom.xml using. This would avoid downvotes and the close vote and makes answering a lot easier.

Comment: Ok, I'l do it, thank you

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with the version of fastexcel you try to use the maven release plugin but did not configure it correctly. The plugin needs the scm developer connection like described in https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/usage.html. If you just want to update versions automatically use mvn versions:use-latest-versions or just change it manually, since you only have one depedency :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The git repo is not equal the maven lib. You download maven libraries from the [offical maven repository](http://central.maven.org/maven2/). The maintainer of the library needs to upload his artifact to the central repository when he builds a new release after that you can use this.

To see which version is usable you can use a maven search website like https://search.maven.org.

The dependency org.dhatim:fastexcel has a version 0.9.4 (same as the github release).

So it seems the developer already uploaded it but did not correct his Readme in the repository. So you can just use 0.9.4 in your pom.xml.

So always check the maven search site and if something is missing you can always add an issue to github to ask the developer uploading it.

There are also this more or less recommended possibilites to get library as a workaround:
Checkout and build the project by your self and add the jar file to:

1. something like nexus as own repository hosting (a organization normally has a maven proxy which could be used)
2. add it to the pom.xml as system scope dependency where the jar must be located on your system
3. use mvn install on the fastexcel project and change the version in your pom.xml to 0-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I tried the 0.9.4 version, but the commit changes are not present there.

Comment: @Andranik added some other possibilties which requieres you to build the jar by your own. But these would be dependend on your system and could not be easily used by others. But can be ok for a short workaround. Except for the nexus solution which is always a good idea for every company.

Comment: You were right, the artifact was uploaded to the central repository, but the readme was not changed. I was wrong about commit changes. Thank you very much.